# How would you approach to wrap these two meshes together?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, shrinkwrap

Reference Image:
[image: reference]

My Blend file so far:
[image]

The puzzle I made in illustrator and imported as SVG. Cleaned it up

Head model from cg trader
[image]

I've tried height maps and also using wave modifier with the displacement texture to avoid having to have the head as a model, but it didnt quite work the way I wanted.
So, now I can seem to figure out how to wrap the puzzle around the head
Also my puzzle mesh:
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess it's doable with GN

A classic solution would be to separate each piece, create a plane that you put just in front, subdivide it:

[image]

Then select one of the piece, shift select the plane, switch to *Edit* mode, select 3 of its vertices and parent with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>:

[image]

Then give a *Shrinkwrap* modifier to your plane, *Wrap Method > Project* with your head as *Target*. Now when you move your plane the pieces follow and stick to the surface of the head:

[image]

To bend it, subidivide the piece, and try a *Shrinkwrap* modifier, *Wrap Method > Target Normal Project, Snap Mode > Outside*:

[image]

Comment: But this way the puzzle pieces will still be flat? I would like to wrap them on the head model

Comment: I've edited, maybe try a Shrinkwrap modifier on the object

Comment: I created the puzzle in illustrator and imported it as svg. I had to reconstruct the pieces and do the puzzle from the beginning in blender. I shrinkwrapped all pieces seperately, because some of them were getting a very unnatural stretch. Thank you though